# Code Sign error: Provisioning profile does not match bundle identifier

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins

i'm getting below error while building, Can you please help me on this.

> Check dependencies Code Sign error: Provisioning profile does not
>   match bundle identifier: The provisioning profile specified in your
>   build settings (“EXAMPLE test - Open”) has an AppID of
>   “com.test.example” which does not match your bundle identifier
>   “com.test.exampleTests”. CodeSign error: code signing is required for
>   product type 'Unit Test Bundle' in SDK 'iOS 8.3'

Answer (score 6):

Change your Bundle ID to com.test.example in the info.plist file.
Or else create a new provisioning profile , with the app id com.test.exampleTests.
After doing one from the above, clean the project and rebuild it.

Comment: I changed the widget id in the project's root config.xml and that worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have changed the bundle id of your project to com.test.example, go to exampleTestsTests target and change the bundle id there as well to resolve the issue.

Comment: I haven't changed the bundle id. I have just reset the distribution profile